# Copying file seems just fine only to find it's corrupt later

Tags: copy, data-corruption

It just happened for 2nd time. I copied a file to an USB drive. (using nautilius) all finished seemingly fine. Only to find out later that the file is corrupt and unusable. 
File size and everything seems the same though but it can't be opened.

What might have caused that and how to prevent it?

Comment: Can you confirm that the file contents are different? You could compare their hash sums (e.g. `md5sum /path/to/file` will print 32 characters or 128 bit, `sha256sum /path/to/file` will print 64 characters or 256 bit). If the hashes of both files are the same, they were not corrupted and your problem is somewhere else, maybe the device was mounted with a `noexec` flag?

Comment: That happened to me too, files diapered or was defunct, turned out it was the USB cable that had a bad soldering or a partly broken lead, Check your cable before more disappears!

Comment: This can happen with plain `cp` not just when copying through nautilus. The file size may be the same, but the copied file can be confirmed to not be identical via `diff` or `cmp`. Confirmed with a SanDisk Cruzer Blade 32GB disk, copying a 9GB file. One byte came out different as per the output of `cmp -b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities.

It could be that the USB drive is failing.  This can happen if it's been used a lot.

Removing the USB drive without unmounting it first could also cause data corruption.  To unmount from nautilus, click on the eject button next to the USB drive.  Unmounting ensures that all data has actually been written to the USB disk.

You can verify that the file has been copied successfully using md5sum.  To do this, open a terminal and type in

```
md5sum path/to/original.file /media/user/disk/copied.file
```

where *path/to/original.file* is the file you copied, and */media/user/disk/copied.file* is the copy on your USB.  You should see two lines such as

```
b42a1f78f6cecf01ef8f65c77f5b6006  original.file
b42a1f78f6cecf01ef8f65c77f5b6006  /media/user/disk/copied.file
```

If the two number on the left match (as in this case), you can be pretty sure that the file has been copied successfully.  Just in case, if it's very important, I would unmount the USB drive, pull it out, then plug it back in, before using md5sum.